# Django related_name naming best practice in case of multiple relations

Tags: django

After a year of Django experience I found out that I am not quite sure that I use Django `related_names` correctly.

Imagine I have three models

```
classA(models.Model):
    pass
classB(models.Model):
    pass
classC(models.Model):
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(classA)
    modelB = models.ForeignKey(classB)
```

Fine. Now I am thinking of adding `related_name` to classC's modelA and modelB, but the frustrating think is that I cannot use the same name for two fields. In other words, this code is apparently wrong

```
 classC(models.Model):
            modelA = models.ForeignKey(classA, related_name = 'classC') # wrong
            modelB = models.ForeignKey(classB, related_name = 'classC') # wrong
```

On the other hand, coming up with an approach like this:

```
classC(models.Model):
        modelA = models.ForeignKey(classA, related_name = 'classA') # wrong
        modelB = models.ForeignKey(classB, related_name = 'classB') # wrong
```

would result in a very misleading (at least for me) code. Consider this:

```
obj = classA.filter(classC__in = classA_qs)
```

So such naming results in a very disruptive code `classC = classA_instance`.

What is the best practice in terms of naming `related_name`s. And is there something I am missing about ManyToManyFields ? Actually, I have a large project, but I've never used ManyToManyFields, always going for a third table like classC in the example. Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Using made up names like `classA` makes the question confusing because they are not descriptive. The first example looks incorrect - you should be able to use `related_name='classC'` for multiple fields in the same model. The example query `classC.filter(...)` is on the model with the foreign key, so it doesn't use related name at all.

Comment: Stupid me. Indeed. But I remember that once Django punished me for using the same related_name within a model

Comment: I've updated the part concerning filter()

Comment: The `filter()` part still doesn't make sense. I think you mean that `related_name='classA'` results in queries like `classA.filter(classA__in=classC_qs)`. As you say, this doesn't make sense, so you shouldn't use `related_name='classA'` for a foreign key to `classA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using variable related_names that way you can relate them according to their app and class.

```
class ClassB(models.Model):
    readers = ForeignKey('Reader',
            related_name='readable_%(app_label)s_%(class)s_set+')
```